# Pentaho Excel File download

Tags: excel, pentaho

I want to develop a module which can download any number of different excel files from FTP Server depending on end user requirement. Any ideas on building this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have got nothing about reinventing the wheel. The wheel was a good invention in the first place, and I would worry more of the invention than are not reinvented.

Therefore:

If the `Microsoft Excel Input` of a transformation cannot reach your file server, download them in a job before with one of the `File transfer` steps.

Then put your user requirement in a set of parameters and launch kitchen with that set of parameters. This can be done in a bat (or sh) file or... or...

Or, wait a minute, are you looking to do something useful for the community: write a plugin for an interactive input step: something like the `Data grid` step which would open a screen on your terminal and ask for values. Of course the real fun is going to come when users will ask you how to use it in remote batch jobs...